# Authentication error when reading Microsoft Graph /synchronizationProfile

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need to read the list of `synchtonizationProfile` entities. I get accessToken using `grant_type=code` and requested permissions for `EduAdministration.Read` and `EduAdministration.ReadWrite` (as specified in the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/educationsynchronizationprofile_list)).

But when I try the request, I get the following error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationError",
        "message": "Error authenticating with resource.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "1a47270e-f902-48af-81cc-5ed8e279b050",
            "date": "2017-12-21T12:20:27"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem only with the `/synchronizationProfiles` endpoint.

What is the problem? And how to solve it?

Comment: Have you requested Admin Consent for these scopes?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Yes, i requested Admin Consent. But it problem already solved by removing trailing slash from resource. Resource was [https://graph.microsoft.com/](https://graph.microsoft.com/) and now [https://graph.microsoft.com](https://graph.microsoft.com).